# get images from an string upload them and replace with new links

Tags: php, regex, dom, preg-replace

I have a string that contains text and photos as you can see bellow.
My code so far get all the images and upload them into a folder.
I need to replace the new uploaded links with the correct oreder.

```
$nextstep = "Hello there this is image 1 <img src='http://www.demosite.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01.jpg' width='653' height='340' alt='xxx' title='xxx'> !! And Now you can see image number 2 <img src='http://www.demosite.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02.jpg' width='653' height='340' alt='xxx' title='xxx'>";

$string = $nextstep;
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($string);
$images = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($images as $image) { //STARTING LOOP
    echo "</br>";
    echo $image->getAttribute('src') . "\n";
    echo "</br>";
    $urlimg = $image->getAttribute('src'); //IMAGE URL
    $URL = urldecode($urlimg);
    $image_name = (stristr($URL,'?',true))?stristr($URL,'?',true):$URL;
    $pos = strrpos($image_name,'/');
    $image_name = substr($image_name,$pos+1);
    $extension = stristr($image_name,'.');
    if($extension == '.jpg' || $extension == '.png' || $extension == '.gif' || $extension == '.jpeg'){
        $img = '../images/' . $image_name;
        file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($url)); //UPLOAD THEM ONE BY ONE
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the correct order and how is that defined?

Comment: fo e.g "hello you can see the flower (image of a flower), and now you can see a tree (image of a tree) so replaced urls must be the flower first and the tree the second

Comment: But when are reading them how do you know what is first vs. second/third/etc... or is this a one time run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear what the desired outcome is here. It sounds like you want to change the `src` URL in your existing string to the one where you've saved the images. If this isn't the case please do try updating the question for more clarity.

*Here's a simple way to break down the problem...*

### Step 1 - Extract the img tags from DOM using source string

```
$html = <<<'HTML'
Hello there this is image 1 <img src="http://www.demosite.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01.jpg" width="653" height="340" alt="xxx" title="xxx"> !! 

And Now you can see image number 2 <img src="http://www.demosite.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02.jpg" width="653" height="340" alt="xxx" title="xxx">
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$imgs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');

// Store the list of image urls in an array - this will come in handy later
$imgURLs = [];
foreach($imgs as $img) {
    if (!$img->hasAttribute('src')) {
        continue;
    }
    $imgURLs[] = $img->getAttribute('src');
}
```

### Step 2 - Save the image in a different location

```
$newImgURLs = [];          // new modified URLs where images were moved
$newPath    = '../images'; // wherever you're saving the images
foreach($imgURLs as $imgURL) {
    /**
     *  Use parse_url and pathinfo to break down the URL parts and extract the
     *  filename/extension instead of the fragile implementation you used above
     */
    $URLparts     = parse_url($imgURL);
    $file         = pathinfo($URLparts['path']);
    $fileName     = $file['filename'] . '.' . $file['extension'];
    $newFileName  = $newPath . '/' . $fileName;
    $newImgURLs[] = $URLparts['scheme'] . '://' .
                    $URLparts['host'] . $file['dirname'] . '/' . $newFileName .
                    (isset($URLparts['query']) ? ('?' . $URLparts['query']) : null) .
                    (isset($URLparts['fragment']) ? ('#' . $URLparts['fragment']) : null);
    // download image and save to new location
    file_put_contents($newFileName, file_get_contents($imgURL));
}
```

### Step 3 - Modify the img src URLs to new path

```
foreach($imgs as $i => $img) {
    $img->setAttribute('src', $newImgURLs[$i]);
}
echo $dom->saveHTML(); // new updated DOM
// or just create a new $html string from scratch using the new URLs.
```

Comment: this $imgURLs = []; is marked as error. do you know why?

Comment: Probably because you're using an unsupported version. [Short-hand array syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php) has been around since PHP 5.4.0 and if you're using anything older than that you're way out of date. See [PHP EOL reference](http://php.net/eol) for more information and which versions of PHP are no long supported.

Comment: images are uploaded but in new echo $dom->saveHTML(); it shows the old url. Do you believe that the problem is that Short hand array is highlited as an error? is there any compatible way? Thank you so much for your time Sir. I am using php 5.5.3

Comment: If you were using PHP 5.5.3, you would not get a syntax error for that. Perhaps share the actual error? It might be something else?

Comment: i found out that all image srcs keep the original url and added ../images/uploaded image . jpg so i need to remove this original url

Comment: i just modify the $expStr=explode("../images",$newImgURLs[$i]);
$resultString="../images".$expStr[1];
$img->setAttribute('src', $resultString); and it's ok now

Comment: Thanks @JensTörnell ... missed that one :) Such an old question too